# Node Js - File System cannot find files

Tags: node.js, filesystems, nestjs

I'm using NestJs and using HTTPS SSL Protocols in the main.ts.
But there is an issue I have found when using the file system to look up the certificate and key file, the Node Js file system cannot find the certificate and key file, and returning

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './secrets/localhost.crt'`

For the details, here is my root directory folder:

[image]

And the `main.ts` file :

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as fs from 'fs'

async function bootstrap() {

  const httpsOptions = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/localhost.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/localhost.key')
  }

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    httpsOptions
  });

  await app.listen(port);
}

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify these files as [assets](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets) in `nest-cli.json` so that these files can be distributed to the output directory. For example:

```
"assets": ["./secret"]
```